# Link to a fan page from a Facebook profile page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

How do I put a link to a fan page on my personal Facebook profile page?

Comment: Link on your wall or on the sidebar thing?

Answer (score 2):

Depends where on your page you mean.

1. From the Publisher, will feed into your wall and your friends' news feeds
   [image: Insert link from the publisher]
2. If you are associated with them you can [add them as employer](https://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=eduwork) and it will show in the info section as well as the top of your profile page. Similarly you can add the page as

   - [Arts and Entertainment](https://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=entertainment)
   - [People Who Inspire You](https://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=philosophy)
     These will show on your info page though.
     [image: Enter link as an employer]
3. Profile pages used to have a small blurb section but this has been removed.
4. If you represented a next fan page, you can add the page as a favorite

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Here is where everyone is complaining about this problem: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=23798139265&topic=15996#topic_top

Comment: I tried solution #1 but it doesn't work. As for #4, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you clarify?